# 0.0204081632... as a repeating fraction

Tags: decimal-expansion

I calculated $\left(\frac17\right)^2$ and the calculation returned a decimal where a series of numbers going up by an exponent of 2 were all concatenated together at the end of the decimal. the number looked like this:

```
0.02040816326530612...
```

It started with 02, 04, 08, 16, 32, and kept going until the hundredth digit inevitably started interfering with previous parts of the pattern. Is there a way to somehow encode all of this into a repeating decimal? because I'm certain that it repeats eventually.

Comment: It repeats after $42$ digits

Comment: Note that $49$ is a factor of $10^{42} - 1$. This indicates that the decimal must repeat every 42 places (though it could repeat even more often - it could repeat every 2 places, for instance).

Comment: Thanks, but how did you get 42?

Comment: Cf. [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)

Comment: Besides the repeating decimal form, we might also write it as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n}{100^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{50^n}$.